# Updating time using @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a question regarding `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` .
I have a entity class which is having property like :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", length = 7)
    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return this.lastModifiedDate;
    }
```

The existing value of LAST_MODIFIED_DATE is

> 11/05/2016 22:11:31

Now I am updating this with value of `11/05/2016 22:11:31`. But modified time is not getting reflected.
I am calling the setter like this :

```
obj.setLastModifiedDate(new Date()) ;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

> FYI, All other colums getting updated properly

Comment: you are updating with the same value ? .. lol .. i think a copy/paste problem in your question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 values for `@Temporal`

```
TemporalType.DATE
```

Only year, month and day. No hour, minute and second

```
TemporalType.TIME
```

Ony hour, minute and second. No year, month and day

```
TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
```

Have everything. Year, month, day, hour, minute and second

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use : @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date;
```

you can new with obj.setDate(new Date());

this will have both dates and time.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) // for only time also
```

Also you might need to recreate your table. Sometimes JPA will not understand the difference